# Dependencies on other services and infra on service start

Tags: architecture, microservices

There is micro-service which depends on

- DB
- Queue
- And bunch of other services

While on startup it makes connections to QB and Queue
Should application not start if one of those are down?

Some time queue is not available (ideally should available 99.9999 time but) so application start up fails.

Should application start and retry for problems or start up fail if there is some temp problem with queue or DB or other service ?
What is best practice ?

Also note that start up time also increase because of making connections to attachable services or infra.

Comment: According to 12 factor app - application should start fast and stop fast so that it can auto-scale as per demand.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this with the given information. Is it guaranteed that you're running other nodes when this particular problematic instance is on startup? How long does it take to restart vs retry? What happens if it doesn't start? Do you stop the rollout / deployment? Or does it continue rolling out to other nodes, potentially poisoning the infrastructure? Can you conclusively say it was due to a DB / Queue connection versus some other component failing? How many times have retrying it mitigated the issue...

Comment: Let me simplify question - if your service depends on queue then should start of service fail if queue is temp not available ?

Comment: What happens if you don't start the service? Let's say you crashed it instead of retrying. What does this effect exactly? You're asking to generalize an answer for this but it depends on the business case as well. Can you afford crashing that server, or is that something that has to be running with 5 9's?